# Stripe - timed out connecting to remote host. Works in test but not in prod

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

My stripe configuration is timing out as the user is redirected *back* from the Stripe checkout screen to my app. It works fine in testing but in prod the loading wheel just spins once the user hits "submit" after entering their payment information.

In the Stripe Customer Dashboard, I can see that the customer account has been created and that the subscription has been setup but the redirect is critical for triggering my webhook, which is responsible for building critical functionality for the user (subscription tier determines features within the app and can't be setup).

I can *also* see the error `Timed out connecting to remote host` on my production webhook in the Stripe Dashboard.

From my understanding, the code is hung up in the `createCheckoutSession` function on the `success redirect` row below:

```
      success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
```

I'm not sure if the either the webhook code or front end code play a role in this but I've included them as well.

**Create checkout**

```
module.exports.createCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
    const { currency, selectedPriceId } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

    const cloakedPriceId = pricing[selectedPriceId].priceId;

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (((!req.user.stripeId) || (req.user.stripeId.length < 1))) {
            const new_stripe_customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.user.email,
                    metadata: {
                    user_id: req.user.id.toString(),
                },
            });

            let update = {};
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, update);

            if (!req.user.stripe_customer) {
                req.user.stripe_customer = {};
            } else {
                req.user.stripe_customer[currency] = new_stripe_customer.id;
            }
            user.stripeId = new_stripe_customer.id;
            await user.save();
            try {
                const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                    mode: "subscription",
                    customer: req.user.stripe_customer[currency],
                    customer_email: req.user.email,
                    line_items: [
                        {
                            price: cloakedPriceId,
                            quantity: 1,
                        },
                    ],
                    success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                    cancel_url: `${webUrl}/canceled.html`,
                });
                return res.redirect(303, session.url);

            } catch (e) {
                res.status(400);
                return res.send({
                    error: {
                        message: e.message,
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            try {
                const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                    mode: "subscription",
                    customer: req.user.stripeId,
                    line_items: [
                        {
                            price: cloakedPriceId,
                            quantity: 1,
                        },
                    ],
                    metadata: {
                        user_id: req.user.id.toString(),
                    },
                    success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                    cancel_url: `${webUrl}/canceled.html`,
                });
                return res.redirect(303, session.url);

            } catch (e) {
                res.status(400);
                return res.send({
                    error: {
                        message: e.message,
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    req.flash('error', "You must login before changing billing");
    res.render('/login');
};
```

**Webhook**

```
module.exports.stripeWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    let data;
// Check if webhook signing is configured.
    const webhookSecret = stripeWebhookSecret;
    if (webhookSecret) {
        // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
        let event;
        let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
        console.log("signature ", signature);

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                req.body,
                signature,
                webhookSecret
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        // Extract the object from the event.
        data = event.data;
        eventType = event.type;
    } else {
        // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
        // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
        data = req.body.data;
        eventType = req.body.type;
        console.log("event type ", eventType);
    }

    switch (eventType) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded': {
            // add name to stripe customer in stripe dashboard
            const paymentIntent = data.object;
            // console.log("payment intent ", paymentIntent);
            const customer = paymentIntent.customer;
            // console.log("customer ", customer);
            const name = paymentIntent.metadata.name;
            // console.log("name ", name);

            // use stripe customer id to check customer subscription status
            const customerSubscription = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
                customer,
                {
                    expand: ['subscriptions'],
                }
            );
            console.log("customer subscription ", customerSubscription);
            // const user = await User.findById(customerSubscription.metadata.user_id);
            // FIND USER BY email
            const user = await User.findOne({ email: customerSubscription.email });
            console.log("user ", user);

            // get product name from stripe product api
            const product = await stripe.products.retrieve(
                customerSubscription.subscriptions.data[0].items.data[0].price.product
            );
            console.log("product ", product);
            const productCap = product.name;
            productName = productCap.toLowerCase();
            const subscriptionDetails = customerSubscription.subscriptions.data[0].status;
            console.log("product name ", productName);
            user.product = productName;
            user.subscription.active = subscriptionDetails;
            await user.save();

            break;
        }
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            // Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
            // You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
            break;
        case 'invoice.paid':
            // Continue to provision the subscription as payments continue to be made.
            // Store the status in your database and check when a user accesses your service.
            // This approach helps you avoid hitting rate limits.
            break;
        case 'invoice.payment_failed': {
            // The payment failed or the customer does not have a valid payment method.
            // The subscription becomes past_due. Notify your customer and send them to the
            // customer portal to update their payment information.
        }
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.failed': {
            // The payment failed or the customer does not have a valid payment method.
            // The subscription becomes past_due. Notify your customer and send them to the
            // customer portal to update their payment information.
        }
            break;
        default:
        // Unhandled event type
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

**Client code**

```
   <title>Checkout</title>

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="text-center">Confirm plan selection</h2>
        <p>Confirm plan before entering billing information</p>
    </div>
    <form action="/users/stripe/create-checkout-session" method="POST">

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                        <h4 class="my-0 fy-normal">Basic</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29.99
                            <small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                            <li class="p-1">2 QR links</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Up to 35 participants per activation</li>
                            <li class="p-1">5gb storge</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Cancel or freeze whenever</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button class="button btn-primary btn-lg" type="hidden" id="selectedPriceId"
                            name="selectedPriceId" value="basic">Confirm Basic</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                        <h4 class="my-0 fy-normal">Scaled</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99.99
                            <small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                            <li class="p-1">7 QR links</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Up to 100 participants per activation</li>
                            <li class="p-1">10gb storge</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Cancel or freeze whenever</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button class="button btn-primary btn-lg" type="hidden" id="selectedPrice" name="selectedPriceId" value="scaled">Confirm Scaled</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
                    <div class="card-header py-3">
                        <h4 class="my-0 fy-normal">Enterprise</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$199.99
                            <small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                            <li class="p-1">10 QR links</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Up to 1000 participants per activation</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Unlimited storge</li>
                            <li class="p-1">Cancel or freeze whenever</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button class="button btn-primary btn-lg" type="hidden" id="selectedPriceId"
                        name="selectedPriceId" value="enterprise">Confirm Enterprise</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>       
 </form>
```

Any idea why my `success redirect` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

These errors indicate that requests from Stripe to your production server are timing out.  It's likely that this has more to do with network configurations.  I think checking what kind of security settings are applied to your production environment is a good next step here.

If you need to allow-list specific domains or IP addresses for incoming traffic you can find the list of Stripe domains and IP addresses [here](https://stripe.com/docs/ips)

Comment: Hi @ryanM I think you're on to something. My webhook isn't working and I think it's because I have the wrong endpoint in my stripe webhook.

I'm currently using `https://mywebsite.com/users/stripe/webhook` and am wondering if I need to be using `https://theherokugiturl.com/users/stripe/webhook` but can't find too much documentation so I may ask a new question. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.